# react-select Is it possible to move selected values from isMulti?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I want to position selected items from Select isMulti elsewhere.

What I did before was hide the selected values, and save the selected values on some state and display in other place.

But this way I don't have the clear indicator for this element.

```
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({secondarySelectedOptions: event});
  };

  render() {
    const { secondarySelectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Select
           isMulti
           name="secondary"
           options={this.state.options}
           styles={{
             multiValue: base => ({
               ...base,
               display: "none"
             }),
           }}
           onChange={this.handleChange}
           value={secondarySelectedOption}
         />
      </>

    )
```

```
<div className='half-width'>
  {this.state.secondarySelectedOptions.map((item) => (
    <div>{item.value}</div>
  ))}
</div>
```